# Java - String with two followed parenthisis error

Tags: java, string

I have a problem as I'm trying to check if a string has any of these characters:

```
{ "[(]", "[)]", "AND", "OR", "NOT", "NEAR", "NEAR/1", "NEAR/2", "NEAR/3", "NEAR/4", "NEAR/5", "NEAR/6", "NEAR/7", "NEAR/8", "NEAR/9" }
```

I've got this function

```
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String inputStr, String[] items) {
    return Arrays.stream(items).parallel().anyMatch(inputStr::contains);
}
```

which works perfectly except when the string being compared is something like

```
"((Words and numbers))"
```

that is, with two followed parenthisis.

Shouldn't it check the same way as it does when a string has only one couple of parenthisis? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: my first guess is to replace `"[(]"` and `"[)]"` with `"("` respectively with `")"`

Comment: [`String::contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) is using a `CharSequence` to match not regex.

Comment: @Lino wow it apparently worked, which is weird because it WAS detecting there was a character to replace, but then it wouldn't.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments:

> String::contains is using a CharSequence to match not regex.

– Flown

> my first guess is to replace "[(]" and "[)]" with "(" respectively with ")"

– Lino

Answer (score 0):

As my comment worked out for the OP, I'll post it as answer so this question can be resolved.

Replace `"[(]"` and `"[)]"` with `"("` respectively with `")"`.